# Trouble Getting a Function Result Written to External .txt Using Python

Tags: python, iterator, return

To clarify, I am still new to Python and programming in general so please excuse my ignorance.

What I am trying to do is take a list of words, have a user enter their own keyword and combine the two, then print them to a .txt file. I have cobbled together this code below and it accomplishes this to a degree. My problem is that only the first keyword ('kw: ') + the user entered keyword gets written to the key_word.txt file. I get this result by using 'return' in my function. If I use 'print' in my function 'none' get's written to the key_word.txt file.

How can I get my entire list of keywords ('search_kw = ') + the user entered keyword to be written to the .txt file.

```
search_kw = ('kw: ', 'kw1: ', 'kw3 ', 'kw4: ', 'kw5: ', 'kw6: ', 'kw7: ', 'kw8: ')

keyword = raw_input('Enter your keyword here\n > ')

def add_keyword():
    for word in search_kw:
        return word + keyword

text_file = open("/Users/home/Projects/keyword_file.txt", "w")
text_file.write("%s" % search_kw)
text_file.close()

add_keyword()
```

Comment: You might be interested in using the built-in ConfigParser: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

```
search_kw = ('kw: ', 'kw1: ', 'kw3 ', 'kw4: ', 'kw5: ', 'kw6: ', 'kw7: ', 'kw8: ')

keyword = raw_input('Enter your keyword here\n > ')

def add_keyword():
    for word in search_kw:
        # Leave the function, breaking the loop after the first iteration
        return word + keyword

text_file = open("/Users/home/Projects/keyword_file.txt", "w")
# Write search_kw before adding any keywords to it
text_file.write("%s" % search_kw)
text_file.close()

# Only calling add_keyword and the end, and not using the return value
add_keyword()
```

What you probably want is something closer to this:

```
def add_keyword():
    keywords = []
    for word in search_kw:
        keywords.append(word + keyword)
    return keywords

search_kw = add_keyword()
text_file = open("/Users/home/Projects/keyword_file.txt", "w")
text_file.write("%s" % search_kw)
text_file.close()
```

There are many more elegant ways of doing this (e.g. using a generator expression), but this should at least get your example working.

Comment: I am also still only getting "None" written to the keyword_file.txt using this code suggestion.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. It not only works, but I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are opening the file for writing. It may seem confusing but writing to a file and appending to a file are two different operations.

When you write to a file that is open in write-mode `'w'`, Python starts writing from the beginning of the file, so anything that exists in this file already is potentially overwritten.

When you write to a file that is open in append-mode `'a'`, Python knows that there is other stuff in the file that you want to keep and writes to the file after the stuff that is currently there.

try opening you file in append mode:

```
text_file = open("/Users/home/Projects/keyword_file.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

you writing the list and not the string

text_file.write("%s" % search_kw)

try search_kw[x]

Answer (score 0):

You opened the file for writing. Writing opens the file and starts at the beginning (wiping everything out). Appending starts at the end. To open a file in append mode, you use:

`f = open('/path/to/file', 'a')`

To append to a file, you still use the `f.write()` function.

Comment: So, I need to use 'a' in order for it to write the entire contents of the code rather than just the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The right data structure for your case seems to be dictionary.

```
search_kw = {'kw': '', 'kw1': '', 'kw3': '', 'kw4': '', 'kw5': '', 'kw6': '', 'kw7': '', 'kw8': ''}

keyword = raw_input('Enter your keyword here\n > ')



def add_keyword():
    text_file = open("keyword_file.txt", "w")
    for key,_ in search_kw.items(): # iterate over (key,value) pairs in the dictionary
        search_kw[key] = keyword    # associate new value with each key
        text_file.write("%s: %s\n" % (key, search_kw[key])) # write (key,value) pairs to a file
    text_file.close()

add_keyword()
```

Comment: Agreed...a dictionary is probably a better data structure. You can keep the keys and values together nicely, and then do whatever you want with them.

Comment: All that gets written to the keyword_file.txt is "None". What's going wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Note that search_kw has a different form than the original search_kw.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening and closing the file you're writing to BEFORE you do any of the work of capturing user input.

You need to
1) Open the file for writing
2) Throw all the user info you want into it
3) THEN close the file

Python's [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) operator takes care of the file opening/closing for you, like so:

```
search_kw = ('kw: ', 'kw1: ', 'kw3 ', 'kw4: ', 'kw5: ', 'kw6: ', 'kw7: ', 'kw8: ')

with open('keywordfile.txt','w') as text_file:
    for word in search_kw:
        keyword = raw_input('Enter your keyword here\n > ')
        text_file.write("s\n" % word + keyword)
```

Comment: I tried this code suggestion but ran into this error

    `Enter your keyword here
    > ball
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Untitled 6.py", line 6, in <module>
    text_file.write("s\n" % word + keyword)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string     formatting/`